# Why does margin-left: auto; prevent an adjacent block element from starting on next line?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I was playing around with the margin property and noticed something odd. I know that `margin-left: auto;` calculated margin automatically on left side so it ends up on right side and I know that block elements always start on next line. Now why does my p not start on next line and everything is so distorted?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NOqGRO

```css
.item {
  display: block;
  border: 5px solid green;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.item2 {
  display: block;
  border: 5px solid green;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <h1>hello world</h1>

  <div>
    <div class="item" />
    <div class="item2" />
  </div>

  <p>omg</p>
</div>
```

Comment: you want this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zmGvwv ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A classic, you were focused on CSS while the problem was elsewhere. Change this.

```
<div class="item" />
<div class="item2" />
```

To:

```
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item2"></div>
```